# How to say "sixth sense" or "feminine sense" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-request

How does one say "sixth sense" or "feminine sense" in Latin?

Comment: 'Or' or 'and' ?

Comment: @cmw "_[vel](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/73/576)_"

Answer (score 4):

**Sensus sextus, sive sensus muliebris.**

[*Sensus*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/16504/78) is a perfectly fine word to use, and in fact *sensus sextus* is in use in nineteenth century Latin (at least, probably earlier if you look), which a quick Google search confirms. I don't believe a Classical citation for it exists, but they were familiar with the [*quinque sensus*](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/684/1/31/50-59,67-71,103-107#31).

Either *femininus* or *muliebris* would have worked, but I chose the latter to avoid the grammatical associations with *femininus*. I don't believe either are attested with *sensus* in antiquity, but once again Neo-Latin gives an attestation, as I've found [sensus muliebris](https://books.google.com/books?id=xGamnFbzomQC&pg=PT26&lpg=PT26&dq=%22sensus+muliebris%22&source=bl&ots=brtrETC9W5&sig=ACfU3U1iEW_46LQ2cbZVaLgL24V1U7treA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0kr6dyo70AhUkmeAKHdrHDvsQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22sensus%20muliebris%22&f=false) in a sixteenth century text of Philo Judaeus, though the index points to a page in Greek, not Latin.

[*Sive*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/278/78) is common in titles of works, and functions similarly to *vel*.