# "A specific type of solution for a specific type of problem"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

Imagine I was having this discussion with my friend the other day:

- Me: I need to hang up this picture on the wall. Do you have a hammer?
- Him: Unfortunately, all I have is a sledgehammer. Would you like to borrow it?
- Me: Thank you for offer, but I am afraid this wont work. I need a small hammer to delicately hammer a nail into the wall without breaking the wall altogether. A sledgehammer is very big and heavy - if I were to use a sledgehammer for this task, I would probably miss where I wanted to swing and end up breaking the whole wall!
- Him: Ah, I understand! A sledgehammer is not well suited for this problem! You need a smaller hammer, something more suitable for this problem!

In this case, I would be looking for a Latin expression to summarize the essence of this conversation. I want to say **"for a specific problem, a specific solution".**

I tried to look online for this and the closest Latin expression I could find was "ad hoc" - but I was hoping to find a more precise Latin expression to summarize this idea: "for this specific problem, a specific solution".

Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: I'm sure there's an equivalent Roman or Greek expression for this couched in more metaphorical language, which I think suits it better than the chosen words. Think along the lines of Aesop's *Fables*. I'll keep looking, though so far I haven't found the right one yet.

Answer (score 3):

It was surprisingly difficult (to me at least) to find a nice classical equivalent for the modern pair: *problem-solution*. In Late Latin we can find *problema solvere* but the term *problema* seems to be more suited for a technical/a riddle rather than a trouble/difficulty.

For "a way out" (as a solution) there are several alternatives like *exitus* and *via*, but I could not find the corresponding term for *problem*. It is as if the authors simply avoid the (abstract) term as in: *inveniam viam aut factiam* or *difficilius est exitum quam principium invenire*; I am almost prompted to also avoid the term *problem* by using the dative, like: *for everything a solution*. However, another problem with *exitus* and *via* is they are relatively broad in meaning. Another option is *solutio* though I'm not sure it is actually better.

Tying to inquire this problem from *problem* yielded the options: *difficultas* and *negotium*; from those two I would pick *negotium* since *difficultas* might be little too strong and usually implies pain and suffering - not so apt to describe a situation as described in the post of missing the right hammer; in that respect *negotium* seems quite right as it usually implies an issue/occupation/trouble. [Meissner](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/50280/50280-h/50280-h.htm) brings *negotium expedire* as "to arrange, settle a matter". I think it is a good match for "solving a problem/issue"; the problem now is that I didn't find the noun for *expedire*. Doing a little corpus research on *negotium* I finally found what was previously escaped me: **magnum negotium, cuius exitum non extimesco** (A big problem whose solution I fear not; Cicero).

Unfortunately, the sense of *exitus* in that passage is rather result/outcome/conclusion and not "a solution" as [one translator has it](https://anastrophe.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/perseus/citequery3.pl?dbname=LatinAugust21&query=Cic.%20Fam.%2011.14.2&getid=1): "there is a serious business on hand, the result of which I do not dread". But I say that this distinction is really not that big as it seems to us English speakers; the idea is a way out; [Lewis and Short dictionary specifically gives](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=exitus2) "A means, method, way, device, solution of a difficulty"; i.e., the *way*. I believe we can add a verb like *reperio* or *invenio* to *exitus* in order to clarify its specific sense as some authors indeed did.

Now, the requested bold part "for a specific problem, a specific solution" calls a known pattern in Latin [*Suum cuique*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suum_cuique) , Let me thus suggest:

> **cuique [proprio] negotio suum [proprium] exitum quo expeditur; huic suum.** (cf. Suam cuique sponsam, mihi meam)

> Every problem has its own solution (by which it is resolved); Also this has its own.

1. I put *proprium* as optional as I think it is little redundant here, but it gives the emphasis on the *specific* part.
2. *quo expeditur* can theoretically be omitted, but I found this as an important addition to clarify the meaning of exitum towards *solution* rather than an *outcome*.
3. I'm still not so happy with that. Maybe it sounds too dramatic. Maybe *solution*, *via* or *remedium* instead of *exitus* would work better.

---

**Edit:**

Trying to seek validation to my suggestion, I saw indeed the pair *(felix) exitus* - *negotuium* shows up and not rare, in some mediaeval texts - but it is very hard to judge the exact translation without deep reading of those texts; However, as far as I could tell, it is more of the Cicero sense above.

Then, I used [luchonacho's "usual trick"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/what-is-sense-of-humour-in-latin#comment14769_6834), and sought a solution to this problem in the Vatican texts. From what I was able to gather, there is no one formula that was used to signify a *solution* (maybe even different translators?), whereas for *problem* the translators were comfortable using *quaestio* (as it was more in the sense of affair/issue as "the issues of humanity" where I think *quaestio* makes more sense in the case here. But maybe I'm wrong here, and *quaestio* is good for the problem of the hammer). At any case here are some formulas (emph. mine):

> "We approach the subject with confidence, and in the exercise of the rights which manifestly appertain to Vs, for no practical **solution** of this question **will be found** apart from the counsel of religion and of the Church." ([source](https://www.vatican.va/content/john-xxiii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_j-xxiii_enc_15051961_mater.html))

> «Confidenter ad argumentum aggredimur ac plane iure Nostro, propterea quod causa agitur ea, cuius **exitus** probabilis quidem nullus, nisi advocata religione Ecclesiaque, **reperietur**». ([source](https://www.vatican.va/content/john-xxiii/la/encyclicals/documents/hf_j-xxiii_enc_15051961_mater.html))

> While it is true that many Christians understand the moral teaching of the Gospel differently from Catholics, and do not accept the **same solutions to the more difficult problems** of modern society, ([source](https://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_decree_19641121_unitatis-redintegratio_en.html))

> Quod si inter Christianos multi non semper eadem ratione atque Catholici Evangelium in re morali intelligunt neque **easdem solutiones difficiliorum hodiernae societatis quaestionum** admittunt, ([source](https://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_decree_19641121_unitatis-redintegratio_lt.html))

> it is for the public authorities "**to seek a solution to these questions**, with the active involvement of individual citizens and social groups." ([source](https://www.vatican.va/content/paul-vi/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-vi_enc_26031967_populorum.html))

> ad publicas auctoritates pertinet **operam dare his quaestionibus dissolvendis**, rem operose communicantibus civibus ac socialibus coetibus. ([source](https://www.vatican.va/content/paul-vi/la/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-vi_enc_26031967_populorum.html))

Comment: For a semantic pair, perhaps nodus and solutio?

Comment: @Kingshorsey, interesting suggestion.